# How to use the Login Items API on OS X from a Qt app?

Tags: macos, qt, qmake

I want my application to register itself in this list:

```
System Preferences -> Accounts -> (your name) -> Login Items
```

I have learned that the way to do this is use `LSSharedFileList.h` to make a few function calls to do this. When I try to do this:

```
#include <LSSharedFileList.h>
```

I get

```
fatal error: 'LSSharedFileList.h' file not found
```

Searching my hard drive, I see that this file is here:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Headers/LSSharedFileList.h
```

Do I need to add something to my `.pro` file in order to get this framework detected? I noticed that if I do `otool -L` on the built executable, these frameworks are linked:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 48.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 62.0.0)
```

So I have this problem of not knowing how to get the build system to find the header file.

Even more helpful on top of that would be C++/Qt code demonstrating how to add an application to the Login Items list, and how to remove it from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've got so far. I'm not satisfied with that hardcoded include path. In the `.pro` file:

```
INCLUDEPATH +=\
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Headers
```

And then the code to install the Login Items entry:

```
void installRunOnLoginHook(QString app_path) {
    QString app_name = QApplication::instance()->applicationName();
    QByteArray app_path_byte_array = app_path.toLocal8Bit();
    CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(
        NULL, (const UInt8 *)app_path_byte_array.constData(), app_path_byte_array.size(), false);
    if (!url) {
        qWarning("unable to create CFURLRef");
        return;
    }
    LSSharedFileListRef login_items = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, NULL);
    if (!login_items) {
        qWarning("unable to get login items");
        return;
    }

    CFArrayRef login_items_array = LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(login_items, NULL);
    if (!login_items_array) {
        qWarning("unable to get login items array");
        CFRelease(login_items);
        return;
    }
    CFIndex count = CFArrayGetCount(login_items_array);
    CFStringRef url_string = CFURLGetString(url);
    CFURLRef item_url = NULL;
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
        LSSharedFileListItemRef item = (LSSharedFileListItemRef) CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(login_items_array, i);
        if (LSSharedFileListItemResolve(item, 0, &item_url, NULL) != 0) {
            qWarning("unable to resolve login item");
            CFRelease(login_items_array);
            CFRelease(login_items);
            return;
        }
        CFStringRef item_url_string = CFURLGetString(item_url);
        CFComparisonResult result = CFStringCompare(url_string, item_url_string, 0);
        CFRelease(item_url);
        if (result == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
            qWarning("found in login items already");
            CFRelease(login_items_array);
            CFRelease(login_items);
            return;
        }
    }

    LSSharedFileListItemRef item = LSSharedFileListInsertItemURL(
        login_items, kLSSharedFileListItemLast, app_name.toCFString(), NULL, url, NULL, NULL);
    if (!item) {
        qWarning("Unable to add to login items");
        CFRelease(login_items_array);
        CFRelease(login_items);
        return;
    }
    CFRelease(item);
    CFRelease(login_items_array);
    CFRelease(login_items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the following into your .pro file:

```
macx {
    LIBS += -framework CoreServices
}
```

and add to includes:

```
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>
```